# Vue Element Ui drag and drop on transfer Element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, element-ui

I have a transfer element from [transfer element](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/transfer) for which I want to add drag and drop functionality which works but dumps a lot of errors into the console.
I have added code to codepen [codepen](https://codepen.io/ilo-ilik/pen/yrRqYM)
which works there but dumps a lot of a hell messages into console like

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The
>   new child element contains the parent.
>       at dragOver
>    I have been trying to add style with `pointer-events: none;` on the dragStart but I lose functionality straight away.

The error to console happens inside **else** statement

```
 if (isBefore(this.selected, e.target)) {
                    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(this.selected, e.target);
                } else {   
                    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(
                        this.selected,
                        e.target.nextSibling
                    );
                }
```

[image]

Could anyone have any suggestions how to fix the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem got solved via using the tutorial from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/